# is it feasible or possible to launch ios app on a specific incoming call using core telephony or some other frameworks

Tags: ios, iphone, core-telephony

1.is it feasible or possible to open/launch ios app and open a specific screen on a specific incoming call using core telephony.Something where i can register my app as observer of incoming call event.

2.if my app is already launched, is there any delegate or notification of core telephony so that i can handle it and open a specific screen.

3.can above requirement filled using notification, as i can think notification will no be able to fulfil this requirement as there may more than one apps having notification, then how ios will decide to open which ios app.

if it's not feasible then what would be alternative or creative idea close to achieve this(open an ios app specific view on incoming call/message/notification centre) behaviour.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve any of the above 3 points. According to HIG, you can not do it. Also apple has not published any of the API to do same. Its not possible with public APIs.

Comment: can you please share apple developer link with me of "According to HIG, you can not do it", so that i can share it with my client.I am looking into HIG docs.Thanks